# Do I need to recompile PHP after changing mysql database engine?

Tags: php, percona

I have built PHP 8.2.5 from source on Debian 11. I have decided to switch to Percona server from Mysql. Do I need to recompile PHP? Should I install any additional libraries to achieve best performance?

Comment: I would expect not, since Percona Server claims to be a fully-compatible replacement for MySQL. Therefore I'd expect you can just use the existing MySQL libraries in PHP to connect your database server (the same as you can with MariaDB databases). Why not try it and see?

Comment: FYI - Percona Server is a _branch_ of MySQL. Percona re-merges current MySQL changes for every release. This is in contrast to MariaDB, which forked from MySQL in 2010 and has gradually made incompatible changes.

Answer (score 2):

> I have decided to switch to Percona server from Mysql. Do I need to recompile PHP?

No.

I've worked with many different variants of MySQL, and I have never once had trouble connecting from php.

If you use MySQL Workbench for schema design, you may need to configure it for Percona, because it adjusts the SQL it emits to match the server.